# pass values from one component to another - flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am new to flex. My package is having 2 components. I want to pass value from one component to another. Please help me.

This is what I have tried.

I have created a property as below in component 2

```
private var _ecboardid : String;


public function get ecboardid():String
{
   return _ecboardid;
}

public function set ecboardid(value:String):void
{
    _ecboardid = value;
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('isPagChanged'));          
}
```

from component 1 when I am trying to assign a value

```
componet1.ecboardid =cmb1.selectedItem.toString();
```

then it is throwing an error like

> Access of posibily undifined property ecboardid through a reference
>   with static type class

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem could be the fact that either cmb1 is not instantiated, or cmb1's selectedItem property is not defined. Please provide more information about the context in which you are using the cmb1 object, specifically, where you instantiate it and/or where you set the selected item.

Comment: Please provide the whole class if possible. This seems anyway a issue with the instances as Romi said, but it will be better if we can see more of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your variable `_ecboardid` public and modifying it directly, this may work.